# Fixed width content in semantic ui

Tags: semantic-ui

Is there a 'correct' way of creating fixed width content in Semantic-UI?

I have a canvas element on the page which must remain a specific size, however when using their grid system it seems to always scale no matter what setup I try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think that's not possible with Semantic UI grids. But using min-width and min-height might help you.

**CSS**

```
.fixed-width {
    width: 300px;
    height:300px;
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

Have a look at this [jsfiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/indvinoth/A3fxz/2/)

Comment: Ah alright, I just wanted to make sure there was not a preferred approach within semantic-ui.

Answer (score 1):

Now Semantic UI supports a 16 column grid for table similar to ui grid. You can set length this way

```
<table class="ui table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="ten wide">Name</th>
      <th class="six wide">Status</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Approved</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jamie</td>
      <td>Approved</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The question was about displaying content, in a fixed width, using a dynamic-based system, on a canvas element. It is an entirely Bad Idea to use html tables for that situation. . . and for laying out anything other than highly consistently shaped data.